# How can I estimate local solar time from direct solar radiation, knowing only latitude and longitude?

Tags: astrophysics, radiation, solar-system

If I know the location (latitude and longitude) of a panel that measures solar radiation (in $\mathrm{W/m^2}$) and that it is at $0$ degrees to the horizon (i.e. facing skyward), can I estimate the local solar time that a particular level will be achieved?

From the reading I have done, I think this is possible in principle if I am happy to ignore local weather and transient atmospheric conditions like air pressure changes.

I think I understand some of the pieces:

- I have been able to calculate a zenith angle from a local solar time, Julian day and latitude...
- ...and use that as an input to the Air Mass formula to get the reduction in power...
- ...and then use $R = 1.353 \times ({0.7} ^ A) ^ {0.678}$ to get a value in $\mathrm{kW/m^2}$ based on that distance.

This came out with some sensible values which match some worked examples I found online.

- Separately, I have been able to calculate elevation from a local solar time and latitude and verify the calculation by looking at a sunrise/sunset calculator.

I think my approach should be:

1. Determine what reduction in power will give the level in $\mathrm{kW/m^2}$ that I want to achieve.
2. Determine the zenith angle that would cause that reduction in power.
3. Determine the elevation angle from the zenith angle (trivial: $\mathrm{elevation = 90^\circ - zenith}$)
4. Determine the local solar time from the elevation and latitude. I think this is just a rearranging of my elevation from LST and latitude formula from the point above.

Unfortunately for me, I am an idiot.  When I try to plug these things together I just get nonsense values. After several hours of getting nowhere, I thought I might do well to validate my approach with the smart people on here; people for whom humanity will never be grateful enough!

It may be I have a simple problem of mathematics and was torn between posting here and on the Math Stack Exchange, but my intuition tells me I may be overlooking some approach that makes sense because of the physical characteristics of the problem...so I thought I'd try here first.

-- EDIT: --

Re. point #1 of my approach, I am using:

$$
A = -\log\left({\frac{10000\times10^{48/113} R^{500/339}}{1353\times1353^{161/339}}}\right)\big{/}\log\left(\frac{10}{7}\right)
$$
to get a reduction in power (air mass) from a $\mathrm{kW/m^2}$ figure.